# Does Uber Price Estimates API return real time price estimate?

Tags: uber-api

I was looking at Uber Price Estimates API at [here](https://developer.uber.com/docs/riders/references/api/v1.2/estimates-price-get). They didn't mention if the returned price estimate is real time estimate or not? Does anyone have any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the endpoint at the documentation you are referencing is real-time estimate.

Comment: I see. Thanks for the quick response!